# MySQL Workbench Automatically Capitalized and Reformatted Section of SQL Script

Tags: mysql-workbench

I was editing a SQL script that I was using in MySQL Workbench 6.3.  To my surprise, I noticed that one section of the code had transformed into all uppercase.  I normally type in mostly lowercase with my own habits for tabs and capitalization.  Somehow, a section of the code was automatically reformatted.

I am not familiar with what option caused this.  Perhaps I made some sort of error in keyboarding while flipping and scrolling through a lot of code.  Is there an autoformatting feature in MySQL Workbench?

How can this type of formatting be done or undone?

A sample of my code before and after follows:

#### Before:

`select * from ReportQA_TEMPA;
    select * from ReportQA_TEMPB;
    select * from ReportQA_TEMPC;
    select * from ReportQA_TEMPD;`

#### After:

`SELECT 
    *
FROM
    ReportQA_TEMPA;
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    ReportQA_TEMPB;
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    ReportQA_TEMPC;
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    ReportQA_TEMPD;`

Comment: Go ahead.  It's the answer I was looking for.  I'll check it in, if you do.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at

```
Edit -> Preferences -> SQL Editor -> Query Editor?
```

There are a couple of "beautifier" and "capitalise" options there.